# HTM Document unable to open in Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I started working for a marketing company who had their intranet file (.htm) set up so non-tech people could open it in Word and edit the hyperlinks or add a new file.

Of course this led to some CSS issues. So I opened it in Dreamweaver, fixed the CSS saved it and now you cannot view the entire document in word any longer?

Can I reformat it so it is accessible to the rest of the staff in Word again?

Answer (score 0):

An option (sorry if you've tried it). Create a new word document, copy and paste the content from a browser window of the intranetfile.HTM into the word document.
Save the word document as an new-intranetfile.HTM. Rename the intranetfile.HTM to old-intranetfile.HTM and rename new-intranetfile.HTM to intranetfile.HTM.

Now you should be able to open the HTM file in word again.

My guess is that when you saved intranetfile.HTM from DreamWeaver it added dreamweaver code which confuses word. Or the hidden files that word saves when it saves an HTM document no longer linked correctly to the intranetfile.HTM and that was the issue.

Dorje